# make elasticsearch rebalance all data after adding nodes

Tags: elasticsearch

So I've been working with a two node cluster for several days now and was able to acquire more hardware.  I've successfully added three more nodes to my cluster.  However I was tracking that when I added the nodes that my shards would balance across the cluster.  This is not happening.

I added two cluster settings

```
cluster.routing.allocation.allow.rebalance:always
cluster.routing.allocation.enable:all
```

does anyone have any ideas on how I get my data to balance across the cluster?

Comment: What do you mean by "balance"? Your third node doesn't have any shards? You mean something else?

Comment: yes, my 3rd 4th 5th nodes are all completely empty.  They have only been a part of the cluster for a few hours.  Does it only rebalance when new shards are allocated?

Comment: Could you send us the result of http://one-your-node:9200/_nodes please?

Comment: not sure if there is a way to upload files on here.  still a bit of a newby.  it's too many characters?  http://pastebin.com/cyqNxDTi

Comment: working on a closed network so it takes me a sec to move files back and forth.

Comment: since I have two nodes that are fully functional can I just use 
"cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip" : "10.0.0.1"
to turn one of the nodes off and then hope it balances the rest of the shards across my cluster?  unfortunately I'm using this right now and don't want to mess up my data...

Comment: everything I read everywhere says that my shards should rebalance pretty much automatically.  But mine don't and I've hardly change the configurations to be honest.  I just removed one of my two original nodes and now half my shards are "unallocated" yet I have 3 nodes with nothing on them!  So confused...

Answer (score 0):

I had too much disk utilization on my new nodes (8% remaining).  I didn't figure this out until I tried to manually allocate a shard on one of the new nodes.  I never saw any errors anywhere else.